# VBA Count rows in Table

Tags: vba, excel

I Have put together a macro to move data from a input area which takes water readings and then puts them into a table on another sheet.

Sheets are "water - Input", "water - Data", table is "water"

I have got the macro to add a new table row and then move the data into the new row.

I have added some text that says Success!, however, I would like to add the row number so that people can look for the record.

This is the first piece of VBA I have written so sorry if its a little rough.

```
Sub waterInput()
Dim the_sheet As Worksheet
Dim table_list_object As ListObject
Dim table_object_row As ListRow
Set the_sheet = Sheets("Water - Data")
Set table_list_object = the_sheet.ListObjects("Water")

'Add new row to table "Water - Data"
Set table_object_row = table_list_object.ListRows.Add

table_object_row.Range(1, 1).Value = ""

'Select $$ from input "Site"
Sheets("Water - Input").Range("C10").Copy

ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Water - Data").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0)

'Select $$ from input "Date"
Sheets("Water - Input").Range("E10").Copy

ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Water - Data").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0)

'Select $$ from input "Meter Number"
Sheets("Water - Input").Range("I10").Copy
ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Water - Data").Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0)


'Select $$ from input "Reading"
Sheets("Water - Input").Range("K10").Copy

ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Water - Data").Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0)

'Clear selected copy
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Sheets("Water - Input").Range("I12").Value = "Success"
Sheets("Water - Input").Range("I13").Value = "Added to line"

'Count rows and return number


'Clear selected Input fields
Sheets("Water - Input").Range("C10,I10,E10,G10,I10,k10").ClearContents

End Sub'
```

Many thanks

Tom

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, for row number you can use following line:

```
Sheets("Water - Input").Range("I13").Value = "Added to line " & table_object_row.Range(1, 1).Row
```

Comment: I have solved by adding a hidden column and then adding   'Range("c" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=""WA""&RC[-1]"'